# Git: how to renormalize line endings in all files in all revisions?

Tags: git, newline

I have an existing repository where line endings are all messed up.  I'd like to rewrite the entire repository and fix line endings once and for all.  There are text files and binary files, let's assume that git's heuristics for detecting binary files will work just fine.

What's the easiest way to repopulate the entire repository with files with normalized line endings?

Comment: I thought all the options were already presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011985/line-endings-messed-up-in-git-how-to-track-changes-from-another-branch-after-a/1060828#1060828?

Comment: tree-filter is prohibitively slow for me.  Even cherry-picking changes one by one is faster.

Comment: slow? But it is a one-time operation you wouldn't repeat everyday. Launch it one evening, get back the next morning. Wouldn't that be possible in your case?

Comment: Turns out it was slow because it was Cygwin.  It's just fine in Linux.

Comment: With Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), you will have `git add --renormalize .`: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309)

Comment: A couple issues: First, if this repository has a parent, you'll need to do `git push -f` to propagate your changes, and then any children of that repo will need to do a new `git pull`. Second, this will play hob with any attempts to do a `git diff` that spans the commit where you made the changes, unless `-w` is used.

Answer (score 71):

Since Git 2.16 (Q1 2018) there is another way (other than deleting the index content), which is a new and safer way to record the fact that you are correcting the end-of-line convention:

**`git add --renormalize .`**

See [commit 9472935](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9472935d81eaf9faed771878c9df0216ae0d9045) (16 Nov 2017) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit af6e0fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af6e0fe3a589d58bfd508c1c6ccbeb38586eb06b), 27 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `add`: introduce "`--renormalize`"

> Make it safer to normalize the line endings in a repository.
> Files that had been committed with CRLF will be committed with LF.
>
> The old way to normalize a repo was like this:
>
> ```
> # Make sure that there are not untracked files
> $ echo "* text=auto" >.gitattributes
> $ git read-tree --empty
> $ git add .
> $ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
> ```
>
> The user must make sure that there are no untracked files,
> otherwise they would have been added and tracked from now on.
>
> The new "add --renormalize" does not add untracked files:
>
> ```
> $ echo "* text=auto" >.gitattributes
> $ git add --renormalize .
> $ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
> ```
>
> Note that "`git add --renormalize <pathspec>`" is the short form for
> "`git add -u --renormalize <pathspec>`".

---

Note: Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019) fixes a bug related to this: "`git add --ignore-errors`" did not work as advertised and instead worked as an unintended synonym for "`git add --renormalize`", which has been fixed.

See [commit 9e5da3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e5da3d055c558fc6492d3b996736ff7e8d115c3) (17 Jan 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1c41824](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c418243a525328b7261ba2c1f2cd93fd52191a2), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `add`: use separate ADD_CACHE_RENORMALIZE flag

> [Commit 9472935](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9472935d81eaf9faed771878c9df0216ae0d9045) (`add`: introduce "`--renormalize`", 2017-11-16, Git 2.16) taught `git add` to pass `HASH_RENORMALIZE` to `add_to_index()`, which then passes
> the flag along to `index_path()`.
> However, the flags taken by `add_to_index()` and the ones taken by `index_path()` are distinct namespaces.
> We cannot take `HASH_*` flags in `add_to_index()`, because they
> overlap with the `ADD_CACHE_*` flags we already take (in this case,
> `HASH_RENORMALIZE` conflicts with `ADD_CACHE_IGNORE_ERRORS`).
>
> We can solve this by adding a new `ADD_CACHE_RENORMALIZE` flag, and using
> it to set `HASH_RENORMALIZE` within `add_to_index()`.
> In order to make it clear that these two flags come from distinct sets, let's also change the name "`newflags`" in the function to "`hash_flags`".

Also: See [commit e2c2a37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2c2a37545f604988424100ed6b1732eb5f36b55) (07 Feb 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9293bf6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9293bf6f2ee047596d31010520a62f0559cc6097), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `add_to_index()`: convert forgotten `HASH_RENORMALIZE` check

> Commit [9e5da3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e5da3d055c558fc6492d3b996736ff7e8d115c3) (`add`: use separate `ADD_CACHE_RENORMALIZE` flag,
> 2019-01-17) switched out using `HASH_RENORMALIZE` in our flags field for a
> new `ADD_CACHE_RENORMALIZE` flag.
> However, it forgot to convert one of the checks for `HASH_RENORMALIZE` into the new flag, which totally broke "`git add --renormalize`".

---

Git 2.37.3 (Q3 2022), "[`git add --renormalize`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/58ded4a4dca5585f771b905afe70e710a376396f/Documentation/git-add.txt#L186)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---renormalize))</sup> clarifies a corner case

See [commit efae7ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efae7ce6921d3ff9b3c6951d0da3efc9518027fc) (10 Aug 2022) by [Philip Oakley (`PhilipOakley`)](https://github.com/PhilipOakley).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 58ded4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58ded4a4dca5585f771b905afe70e710a376396f), 18 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`doc add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efae7ce6921d3ff9b3c6951d0da3efc9518027fc): renormalize is not idempotent for CRCRLF
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philip Oakley</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Torsten Bögershausen</sup>

> A [bug report](https://lore.kernel.org/git/AM0PR02MB56357CC96B702244F3271014E8DC9@AM0PR02MB5635.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com/) noted that a file containing `/r/r/n` needed renormalising *twice*.
>
> This is by design.
> **Lone CR characters, not paired with an LF, are left unchanged.**
> Note this limitation of the "`clean`" filter in the documentation.
>
> Renormalize was introduced at [9472935](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9472935d81eaf9faed771878c9df0216ae0d9045) (`add`: introduce , 2017-11-16, Git v2.16.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af6e0fe3a589d58bfd508c1c6ccbeb38586eb06b) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f9953d2c365bffed6f9ee0c6966556bd4d7e2f4)) (add: introduce "`--renormalize`", Torsten Bögershausen, 2017-11-16)

`git add` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/efae7ce6921d3ff9b3c6951d0da3efc9518027fc/Documentation/git-add.txt#L191-L193):

> This option implies `-u`.
> Lone CR characters are untouched, thus while a CRLF cleans to LF, a CRCRLF sequence is only partially cleaned to CRLF.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas Yet, you can upgrade Git at any time: http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I prefer to leave files as they are without any automatic conversion (e.g. to avoid converting sh scripts to crlf on Windows or cmd scripts to lf on Linux) by specifying `* -text` in my gitattributes and then deleting and readding the files back with final correct end-of-lines that shouldn't be ever touched by git.

Comment: @JustAMartin Agreed, but shouldn't `git add --renormalize` avoid the delete/add again step?

Comment: Maybe `renormalize` should work on new git versions also for "denornalization" (updating the git stage with file EOLs as they are in current working copy), but I haven't yet had a chance to try it - will keep in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to renormalize your current commit after having set `core.autocrlf` or `text=auto`, so you can have all the line ending normalization in one commit, run these commands:

```
git rm --cached -rf .
git add .
```

To also normalize the files in your working dir, run:

```
git checkout .
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be used without git.  Then, later on, `git commit` the code base.

```
for f in $(find ./ -type f ) ; do
    if grep -qP '\x00' $f ; then
       # file is binary
       continue    
    fi

    perl -pe 'BEGIN{ undef $/} s/\x0d\x0a/\x0a/g;s/\x0d/\x0a/g' -i $f
done
```

The grep is assuming anything containing a null character is a binary file.

perl is used to edit each file in-place.  First, Windows style newlines are changed to Unix style newlines.  Then Mac style newlines are changed to Unix style newlines.

Comment: "_The grep is assuming anything containing a null character is a binary file._" But more importantly, it is also assuming anything NOT containing a null character is a text file. This might corrupt some binary files in your directory!

Comment: I wrote a simple script named `nocr` that's nearly identical to yours, but uses tr instead of perl. It lives in my path and I use it all the time. Your "is this a binary" test is an excellent idea. @wovano: you're right in that this is dangerous, but there's really no non-dangerous way to do this. Ultimately, to be safe, you will have to somehow manually specify which files you want to process. Maybe add a clause that explicitly excludes anything ending with .o, .a, .so, .dat, .bin, and so on, or conversely limit to .c, .cpp, .java, etc.

Comment: @EdwardFalk, the `.gitattributes` file (which did not exist yet in 2011, when this answer was written, but is available since 2018) is the proper and safe way to do this. There's no need to write custom scripts if `git` already implements this functionality. Also note that such a script need to be run regularly, while the `.gitattributes` solutions fixes the problem "once and for all" as requested by OP :)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with `.gitattributes` and do use it where applicable. I only mentioned my `nocr` script because it has uses outside of git. But you're right; if you're trying to fix carriage returns in a git repo, then the other methods listed here are better.