# Git - Weirdness when using .gitattributes to force consistent line endings

Tags: git, line-endings, git-extensions

So, I've recently added a .gitattributes file to one of our repositories to try to force consistent line endings:

```
  # All Perl Sources should use Unix style line endings
  *.pl text eol=lf
  *.pm text eol=lf
```

But both myself and a lot of other developers are encountering a lot of "phantom changes" where git seems to detect the file as "changed" even though there's no change. Every line shows up as added, then deleted.

I suspect it's getting confused about line endings (and thus detecting each line as changed), but what's weird here is:

- I can't reset the file (the reset is completed, but the file remains as an unstaged change)
- Changing the line endings in the affected text file does not affect whether it shows up as a changed file.

Has anyone encountered this before, and is there a way to avoid or resolve this issue?

Comment: If the *checked-in* version of the file has CRLF endings, you must do one "fix the files" pass once, which will change the checked-in version to be LF-only. After that, all will be OK.

Comment: Is there a good way to check what the checked in file has? - in many of these cases the files in question *should* already have LF endings.

Comment: From my experience when a diff shows every line is changed but they appear to be the same, then the change is with the line endings or spaces/tabs.

Comment: The easiest way to see for sure what's in the raw version of a file is to read it out with no end-of-line processing. To do *that*, you can: check it out in a repository with no `core.eol` settings and no `.gitattributes` or similar settings or with `.gitattributes` modified to read `* binary`, so that Git does not touch it; use `git cat-file -p <blob-hash>` to extract the raw blob hash data; or use `git archive` in a similar fashion to the `git checkout` method. But see VonC's answer using `--renormalize`, which is usually the way to go if you need to correct them anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[With Git 2.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309) or more, do at least once:

```
git add --renormalize .
git commit -m "normalize eol files"
git push
```

Then try and clone your repo elsewhere, and check that `git status` behaves as expected.

Make sure you don't have `core.autocrlf` set to `true`.

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

And you can [test for your files eol style](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79702/7490).