# git reset --hard does not revert changes

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

`git status` shows one modified file even I did not touch it. I do not have any local changes. It is build server. I tried to revert file and I run whatever I found in documentation

```sh
git fetch
git checkout -- .
git reset --hard origin/master
git restore xxx/License.txt
```

`git status` always shows

```sh
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   xxx/License.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Running `git diff` shows all lines removed and added. VS Code does not show any difference. I assume it is non printable character. Line ending is CRLF. Encoding UTF-8.
How to revert file?
It is Windows computer. Source provider is AWS CodeComit.

Answer (score 1):

Check first your `git config core.autocrlf` in your local session:

If it is `true` or `input`, set it to `false`.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then clone your repository again, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I would like to know what happened, why and how to fix instead of brute force remove. It is related to coworkers changing line ending and file encoding. I changed autocrlf to false. I was thinking that git 1. Removes file from file system 2. Takes original version 3. When saving to file system changes line ending based on autocrlf. This is not the case since I changed autocrlf. Cloned repo settings do not have autocrlf and system wide is used (listed).

Comment: @zdenko.s Instead of cloning again, you can do a `git add --renormalize .; git restore -- .` (as [explained by torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584041/6309))

Comment: This is not solving problem. Lot of new files are added to index (staged). Among them is problematic file. after `git restore -- .` I am where I was. I checked torek's answer. Bullet 2, i already tried. Bullet 3 is done by coworker and now I face tmodified file issue. Cloning repo did solved problem. What is interesting, when I copy file from newly clonned repo, it is shown as modified. It has to do something with autcrl at the time when repo was cloned.

Comment: @zdenko.s Do you have any .gitattributes files in your repository?

Comment: Yes. Coworker added `* text=auto;
*.ini crlf;
*.txt text eol=crlf`

Comment: @zdenko.s That would explain why a new copied file is shown as modified

Comment: Newly cloned repo uses autocrlf=false and no problem. Old repo causes problem which was cloned with autocrlf=true  
autocrlf was changed after cloning.

Comment: @zdenko.s Agreed. Hence my answer mentioning `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230589/discussion-between-zdenko-s-and-vonc).