# *.bat text eol=crlf but git still changes line ending

Tags: git, powershell, cygwin, gitattributes

I am running Windows 10 and use Cygwin's git on the Cygwin command line and use Windows git in applications like VS Code, PowerShell etc.

I have a `.gitattributes` file with entries like the following:

```
text eol=crlf

*.ahk     text eol=crlf
*.bat     text eol=crlf
*.cmd     text eol=crlf
*.css     text 
*.java    text 
*.js      text 
*.md      text eol=crlf
*.sh      text eol=lf
*.txt     text eol=crlf
*.xml     text
```

However, I am finding that alternating between running `git status` on Cygwin or PowerShell repeatedly shows up all files as requiring modifications depending on which one I last checked them all in with.. how do I get the two to agree and obey my `.gitattributes`?

### In response to the suggestion from @VonC

Tuesday, 2nd of April 2019, 12:32:15 PM

On Cygwin I do this:

```sh
$ git config --global core.autocrlf
false

$ echo "* text=auto" >>.gitattributes

$ git add --renormalize .

$ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
... snip

$ git push
... snip

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And then in PowerShell

```
> git config --global core.autocrlf
false

> git status 
... snip.. every single file listed.. again!
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that, in your Cygwin environment, git config core.autocrlf is set to false

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That way, Git won't change automatically files eol, and will stick to its `.gitattributes` directives.

Comment: I will try that, but why isn't my `.gitattributes` file enough to solve this? Shouldn't project specific configuration override global configuration?

Comment: @RobertMarkBram It should. But eol directives can be influence by that one global setting. Try, as in here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309) a `git add --renormalize .` (with Git 2.21+) to see if your gitattributes directives are enforced.