# Tracking changed files through Git on External Hard Drive

Tags: xcode, git, external, drive

I have a Git repository that i'm working on and i'd like to have the ability to **take it on the go and work on different computers**. I've downloaded it to my external drive, but when i plug it in Computer 2 - Git detects all files as Changed. The files' changes i worked on from Computer 1 are read correctly as Modified/Deleted/Renamed whatever, Git history is also intact, **but all other files are also detected as modified**.

### **Is there a way to sync tracked / modified files properly between computers?**

- Computer 1 - Windows 10 - NTFS
- Computer 2 - MacOS
- External Hard Drive - NTFS

Comment: What does git detect has changed in the files?

Comment: @StephenNewell everything, the entire files

Comment: Is it an EOL issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check first your git config core.autocrlf: set it to false, then [renormalize the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309)

Try first the [`update-index --refresh` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---refresh) (or even [`--really-refresh`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---really-refresh)):

```
git update-index --refresh
git status
```

If not:

```
git add --renormalize .
git status
```

Check then the files added are only the ones you are working on.

Check also for permission changes: using [`git config core.filemode false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257613/6309) would help then.

Comment: @jthill Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: `git add --renormalize .` fixed the issue for me but I'm still not sure why is this happening randomly; sometimes it's working, but then git suddenly stops detecting file changes.