# Will change in filesize be considered as change in git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I have replaced a folder of files in UWP assets. Few files in the folder does not contain any changes in the content. Still those with no changes are shown as modified.

So here my query is, will change in filesize be considered before committing to git eventhough there is no content change.

Could anyone clarify this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the file not change if the size changed? Some bytes must have been added or removed for the size to change.

Comment: I don't see any line changes in the txt file in my asset (still shown as modified).but the old txt file size and replaced ones size are different. So got this doubt.

Comment: You probably have change in line endings

Comment: Can you please help me with how to check that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68722187/7976758

Comment: You could have other whitespace changes too, although `git diff` normally shows such changes.