# NexJS Tailwind not loading styles after cloning a github repository

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, tailwind-css, clone

So I'm following a [React NextJS tutorial](https://youtu.be/CcBHZ0t2Qwc) and everything was fine yesterday, but today I had trouble accessing Sanity backend. After Googling the solution was to comment out tailwindcss: {}, in postcss.config.js.
But then all the styles in the app stopped working, even if I un-commented tailwindcss: {},

Remembering that everything worked last time I pushed to GitHub yesterday I cloned the repo but the issue persists.

Then I started the tutorial from scratch, and both Tailwind and Sanity were working perfectly and they still are. But I was trying to figure out what stops my original app from working.

Been bashing my head for hours now and still can't come up with a solution. I even pushed the now working app, cloned it again, and the clone doesn't work while the original of the clone still works.
I ran both npm i --legacy-peer-deps and Tailwinds installation

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

The npx command told me that tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js already exist.
So I tried cloning the repo, deleting tailwind.config.js, postcss.config,js, and package-lock.json. Also ran uninstall command for Tailwind. And then again ran npm i and Tailwinds installation. But it still doesn't work.

Here's the repo - https://github.com/RUSHWAYC/tikdok-test.git

Here's how it looks like:
[image]

Here's how it should look like:

[image]

Am I missing anything? Any commands that I should be running in the terminal?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of fewer induced hallucinations I figured it out.
So I found a way on how to fix the Tailwind styles not applying.

- Clone the last push to GitHub
- Delete tailwind.config.js | postcss.config.js | package.json | package-lock.json
- Remake tailwind files and package.json (or in my case copy them from the dude whose project I'm copying)
- `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`
- `cd backend` (to go to Sanity backend folder)
- `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`
- `cd ..`
- Don't forget to comment out tailwindcss: {}, in postcss.config.js as it messes up Sanity
- `npm run dev`

So it works now and shows Tailwind CSS applied to the project.

But then, if you git add . there are these errors:

> warning: in the working copy of 'package.json', CRLF will be replaced by LF the next time Git touches it
>
> warning: in the working copy of 'postcss.config.js', CRLF will be replaced by LF the next time Git touches it
>
> warning: in the working copy of 'tailwind.config.js', CRLF will be replaced by LF the next time Git touches it

So `git reset` that.

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf) useful post about the first error. - [Git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)
Basically, it's something dumb that I'm even dumber to understand.
But at the end of the post, they linked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156694/git-how-to-renormalize-line-endings-in-all-files-in-all-revisions) answered question here about git add --renormalize . that fixes the issue - [Git: how to renormalize line endings in all files in all revisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156694/git-how-to-renormalize-line-endings-in-all-files-in-all-revisions)

So after doing all the steps above and writing some code, one should run:

- `git add --renormalize .` and then `git commit -m "Message."`
  There should be no errors like previously this time, and every time you `git commit` next there shouldn't be any issues (unless you edit the files in question).

I also changed the config autocrlf settings to input from true after reading the first article I linked. Not sure if I should, but I did and the article I followed on how to do it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings) - [How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Steps you can follow to fix this issue:

1. Uncomment `tailwindcss: {}` from `postcss.config.js`, then re-run your development server.
2. Completely remove everything, [start from scratch](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs), then only copy/import files you need from the started repository.

Comment: Yeah, I remade the whole project from the scratch and it worked at first.
But the project was in folders test/test/
So I copied all the files and pasted them into a new folder newFolder.
And the issue happened again.
I went back to the test/test/ folders and renamed test/test/ to test/test2/ and the issue started happening in that folder as well.
So then I renamed it back to test/test/ but the issue is still there.
Not sure what's causing this.