# How to apply `.gitattribute` file to all files under a directory?

Tags: git, newline, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

In an arbitrary Git project set up locally, a `.gitattribute` file can be included in the root directory to control special characters depending on environments (using Apache Spark on GitHub as an example):

```
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.cmd text eol=crlf
*.java text eol=lf
*.scala text eol=lf
*.xml text eol=lf
*.py text eol=lf
*.R text eol=lf
```

This file will only be used by Git when commiting new files, which may result in many fragmented commits that don't change file content except special characters (in particular, line separators).

Which Git command can I use to modify all files under a project in one run, regardless of whether it is committed?

Comment: Based on you [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410136/when-committing-a-text-file-in-git-why-could-it-be-violating-gitattribute-fi/76417897?noredirect=1#comment134764394_76417897), I'm assuming that you would want to convert the line endings to `CRLF` in the index when `eol=crlf` is specified for that file extension. Is that correct? Otherwise, if you are ok with the default Git behavior, `git add --renormalize .` will work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I [mentioned with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309), you can apply an updated `.gitattributes` directive with the [`--renormalize` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---renormalize):

```
git add --renormalize .
```

That would apply to all existing files, not just new files.

Comment: thanks a lot, you mean `--renormalize` option?

Comment: @tribbloid Indeed. I have fixed this typo.