# When committing a text file in git, why could it be violating `.gitattribute` file?

Tags: git, newline, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

In one of my git repository, I have added the following `.gitattribute` file to regulate LF/CRLF characters:

```
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.cmd text eol=crlf
*.java text eol=lf
*.scala text eol=lf
*.xml text eol=lf
*.py text eol=lf
*.R text eol=lf

# mimicking apache spark
```

To test its effect, I manually change the line separator of one `bat` file from CRLF to LF, unfortunately, when committing & pushing this change in git, it is accepted despite obviously violating the new `.gitattribute`:

https://github.com/tek/splain/commit/9344551a1b61f0bf725cc2d9b8aecdced1e71c8b#diff-33fbd7a182c496726227993443a3cfea58670618db831c51c273dcd8962c861a

How could it be possible? Is it a bug in git?

Comment: The `text` and `eol` attribute docs tell you the effects they'll have: convert line endings to LF on `add`, convert to whatever `eol` and your platform say on checkout. Can you point out whatever it was that led you to expect anything different?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_eol says that it only has effect when the files are checked out. It won't prevent you from committing something that has different line endings than specified.

Answer (score 2):

This is intentional from Git. By itself, it will never convert line endings to `CRLF` when saving a file to its index. As soon as Git is told that a file extension is associated with `text`, it will take every oportunity to convert the line endings to `LF` when you stage something to be committed with that extension.

This can be explained by the fact that git was initilally developed for Unix which uses `LF`. It's also a matter of consistency for git to deal with text in a uniform way internally when it comes to line endings.

This is usually not a problem since any use of the code in a repository should start with a proper `git clone` which performs the conversion according to the `.gitattributes`, so that line endings are correctly specified in the working directory.

But in some special case where you really need to make git save line endings as `CRLF`, you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76019430/5958842).

Comment: That's a good explanation, but I have to say it is a very strange design: Imagine thousands of delta being indexed and persisted on git without any content change :)