Warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
We fetch the discrepencies of our salesforce org and our bitbucket repository and add commits with differences for each component type:
Steps for automated script:

Create a new branch and checkout to that branch.
Fetch salesforce components (by type) for ex: retrieve all the apex classes using ant that are in repo and created a commit with differences.

But all the commits show a warning for many files:  LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/classes/class_name.cls
Hence, unmodified or unchanged files are also added in the commits due to mismatch in line endings i.e. CRLF & LF or \r\n and \n.
I tried repeating this process using all the configurations and combinations:
# First try
git config core.autocrlf true

# Second try
git config core.autocrlf false

# Third try
git config core.autocrlf input

Also Tried
## .gitattributes
eol=lf 
text=auto

But results are the same, PS: I am using a windows machine.
How to remove these unmodified files?
I dont want to use --ignore-whitespaces as it will also exclude space differences elsewhere in the file not just eol.

This question is similar to: Git replacing LF with CRLF. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Don't forget to renormalize: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/717372
