# copy db file with adb pull results in 'permission denied' error

Tags: adb

I just rooted my Nexus 5 using this method: http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-root-Google-Nexus-5_id49014

I also enabled USB debugging in the developer options.

Then I tried to pull a database file from my device using this command:

```
adb pull /data/data/path.to.package/databases/data /sdcard/test
```

I get `permission denied` error.

I don't have the debugged flag set in that app I tried to access. Is that the reason I can't access that file? If yes, are there any workarounds to access an apps files?

Answer (score 124):

You can use `run-as` shell command to access private application data.

If you only want to copy database you can use this snippet, provided in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504263/998157

```
adb -d shell "run-as com.example.test cat /data/data/com.example.test/databases/data.db" > data.db
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on a stock phone. thanks!

Comment: I wish I could favorite answers, this is the only thing that helped in 20 searches.

Comment: Just a note, you can also use this in `adb shell` itself as `run-as com.example.test sh`

Comment: It says `"run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted"`. What to do?

Comment: Great answer! For anyone grabbing from an emulator leave out the '-d' option.

Comment: This throws run-as: package not debuggable:

Comment: i got "No devices found" error. though emulator is running.

Comment: How do you save file to specific directory?

Comment: @PLOW, this is just shell redirection - the part after '>' is the path to the file where the output of the command will be written.

Comment: Not sure how `cat` would work for binary, files, co instead I did `adb -d shell "run-as com.example.test cp foo /sdcard"` which then allowed me to `adb pull /sdcard/foo` as normal.

Comment: On a linux box (and perhaps macos) if you want to transfer a binary file without glitching it you can always do this: 

       adb shell "run-as <packagename> base64 <targetfile>" > base64 -d <localtargetfile>`

This will base64 encode the file in the pipe.

Comment: oops, I meant to put a pipe and not a redirect there.... FTR:

adb shell "run-as <packagename> base64 [targetfile]" | base64 -d > [localtargetfile]

Comment: Do we need to pay attention to CR and LR (\r\n) characters on windows? I mean how to get binary clean (no LF -> CRLF mangling), as [https://github.com/facebook/fb-adb] mentioned.

Comment: If you want to run this on an emulator, remember the `-e` instead of `-d` above.

Answer (score 26):

Did you try `adb remount` after giving `adb root`?

Comment: adb root gives me an error: 'adbd cannot run as root in production builds'. remount fails as well...

Comment: It suggests that phone doesn't allow `adb root`, hence you might need to try `adb shell` and `su`

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem. My work around is to use adb shell and su. Next, copy the file to /sdcard/Download

Then, I can use adb pull to get the file.

Comment: I tried to copy using cp and got "cp: not found". Managed to do it with "cat source > destination".

Comment: seems like the easiest way for "real" devices, which do not permit `adb root`

Answer (score 17):

This generic solution should work on all rooted devices:

```
 adb shell "su -c cat /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db" > contacts2.d
```

The command connects as shell, then executes `cat` as root and collects the output into a local file.

In opposite to @guest-418 s solution, one does not have to dig for the user in question.

**Plus** If you get greedy and want all the db's at once (eg. for backup)

```
for i in `adb shell "su -c find /data -name '*.db'"`; do
    mkdir -p ".`dirname $i`"
    adb shell "su -c cat $i" > ".$i" 
done
```

This adds a mysteryous question mark to the end of the filename, but it is still readable.

Answer (score 8):

If you get could not copy and permissions are right disable selinux.

Check if selinux is enabled.

```
$ adb shell
$su
# getenforce
Enforcing
```

Selinux is enabled and blocking/enforcing.
Disable selinux

```
# setenforce 0
```

do your stuff and set selinux to enforcing.

```
# setenforce 1
```

Comment: One week looking for this

Comment: The cleanest way!

Answer (score 6):

This answer ended up working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559278/53001

Backup to a file, pull the backup, and then convert it to a tarball and extract it.

```
adb backup  -f myAndroidBackup.ab  com.corp.appName

dd if=myAndroidBackup.ab bs=1 skip=24 | python -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))" | tar -xvf -
```

Answer (score 5):

I had just the same problem, here's how to deal with it:

1. adb shell to the device
2. su
3. ls -l and check current access rights on the file you need. You'll need that later.
4. go to the file needed and: chmod 777 file.ext. Note: now you have a temporary security issue. You've just allowed all the rights to everyone! Consider adding just R for users.
5. open another console and: adb pull /path/to/file.ext c:\pc\path\to\file.exe
6. Important: after you're done, revert the access rights back to the previous value (point 3)

Someone mentioned something similar earlier.

Thanks for the comments below.

Comment: **NONONO**! Why would you ever do this? Horrible answer. This is allowing open permissions for `Owner`,`User`, and `Other` to openly `Read`, `Write`, `Execute`. If this is a file that you need `root` access to, then it is most like a file that should not be able to be touched by some other rogue apps. Do not ever do this. My suggestion is to copy the file `system -> sdcard -> computer` and then delete from sdcard. To put a file back into the filesystem, `computer -> sdcard -> system -> strict permissions`.

Comment: I agree this is a security issue, but it is a quick fix intended for the developer not to waste time on trivia.

Comment: with that answer you'll have security problems because any application will be able to access your database

Comment: you can't `su` on devices

Comment: @MattClark, so you state this is *wow-wow-wow horrible*, but what can you propose as alternative? Disabling SeLinux seems no safer to me, and this is the only solution "that just works"!

Comment: Works with adb pull, but not with adb push, for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a folder in sdcard :

```
adb shell "su 0 mkdir /sdcard/com.test"
```

2. Move your files to the new folder :

```
adb shell "su 0 mv -F /data/data/com.test/files/ /sdcard/com.test/"
```

3. You can now use adb pull :

```
adb pull /sdcard/com.test
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ adb shell
$su
# getenforce
Enforcing
```

now try

```
adb shell
su
chmod 777 /path/to/yout_file
```

exit from shell

open new CMD and try `adb pull /path/to/yout_file`

It will work fine now.

you'll have security problems because of this any application will be able to access your database.

Comment: lol, good ol' lucky 7s. +1, b/c that did the trick, but there should be major **emphasis** on **security problems**.

Answer (score 2):

@guest-418 tips works well:

```
adb -d shell "run-as com.example.test cat /data/data/com.example.test/databases/data.db" > data.db
```

However, if you want to use a GUI, use **Android Studio's Device File Explorer**.

1. Launch **Android Studio**
2. Click on **Device File Explorer** at bottom right-side
   Navigate to your app's file:

   /data/data/path.to.package/databases/data
3. Right-mouse click select **Save As** and save to a local folder

I have been having **Android Monitor** hang on me lately on macOS. **Device File Explorer** works well for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

When executing `adb` commands, by default, a limited privileges user is used, the same kind of limited privilege user that is assigned to an app, and you have requested for all privelages to use all features of the device.

This kind of limited user helps protect your phone from malware, by restricting the access between apps, and the system. This is the reason you are unable to access app data and system data on an unrooted phone. The act of `rooting` means becoming user `0`, the super user of the system, capable of any action, and is the highest privilege. Your apps however, are still secure in that they can not talk to eachother.

Now when accessing secure files, note that you *do not* want to *change the permissions* of the file when you access it, which may allow for vulnerabilities.

An option that you could use instead, is to make a copy of the file on the sdcard as root, modify that as a standard user, and then move it back into the filesystem as root, while preserving the file permissions of the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've updated to Android Oreo, I had to use this script to fix 'permission denied' issue.

This script on Mac OS X will copy your db file to Desktop. Just change it to match your ADB_PATH, DESTINATION_PATH and PACKAGE NAME.

```
#!/bin/sh
ADB_PATH="/Users/xyz/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
PACKAGE_NAME="com.example.android"
DB_NAME="default.realm"
DESTINATION_PATH="/Users/xyz/Desktop/${DB_NAME}"
NOT_PRESENT="List of devices attached"
ADB_FOUND=`${ADB_PATH}/adb devices | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -f 1 | sed 's/ *$//g'`
if [[ ${ADB_FOUND} == ${NOT_PRESENT} ]]; then
    echo "Make sure a device is connected"
else
     ${ADB_PATH}/adb exec-out run-as ${PACKAGE_NAME} cat files/${DB_NAME} > ${DESTINATION_PATH}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but installing [adbd Insecure](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590) worked for me. It makes adb run in root mode on production ("secure") devices, which is what you likely have.

A paid version is also available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd) if you want to support the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours on windows as the following.

```
D:\ProgramFiles\Android> adb pull /data/local/tmp/com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex D:\ProgramFiles\Android\com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex
adb: error: failed to copy '/data/local/tmp/com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex' to 'D:\ProgramFiles\Android\com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex': remote Permission denied
```

My solution:

At first I also made an attempt to use `cat` as [ansi_lumen answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891597/copy-db-file-with-adb-pull-results-in-permission-denied-error/42989794#42989794), but I got into trouble about CR and LR (`\r\n`) characters.
And then I just had to change those file permisions by `chmod` and pulled again to this problem was solved without introducing other problems. After that, may 
 we need to restore their original permissions as [Goran Devs answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891597/copy-db-file-with-adb-pull-results-in-permission-denied-error/24365997#24365997).

So just pay a little attention.

**TL;DR**

My story:

Firstly, I used the `cat` to download all files from android to my windows,

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
:: %~dp0 = D:\ProgramFiles\Android\
SET ThisBatDir=%~dp0
:: adb shell ls /data/local/tmp/com.packagename_dumped_* > %~dp0\dump_file_list.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell ls /data/local/tmp/com.packagename_dumped_*') do call :processline %%a %%~nxa

goto :eof

:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232651/why-the-system-cannot-find-the-batch-label-specified-is-thrown-even-if-label-e
:processline
SET RemoteFullPath=%1
set FileName=%2
:: echo "%RemoteFullPath%|%ThisBatDir%|%FileName%"
call adb shell su -c cat %RemoteFullPath% > %ThisBatDir%%FileName%
goto :eof

:eof
```

However, those downloaded `dex` files were broken because of CR and LR (`\r\n`) characters on windows.
We can use `hexdump` to inspect its content in Hex+ASCII form (or Notepad++ with "View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters" checked). Note, the 5th and 6th byte (0d 0a)).

```sh
ssfang@MONITO ~
$ hexdump -C -n32 /cygdrive/d/ProgramFiles/Android/com.packagename_dumped_1448.dex # a bad dex
00000000  64 65 78 0d 0d 0a 30 33  35 00 f7 8e e4 b5 03 c6  |dex...035.......|
00000010  29 22 98 55 21 e9 70 49  fe c8 e4 cc fa 94 cd 63  |)".U!.pI.......c|
00000020

ssfang@MONITO ~
$ hexdump -C -n32 /cygdrive/d/ProgramFiles/Android/classes.dex # a normal dex
00000000  64 65 78 0a 30 33 35 00  b5 73 03 3a 0b 9d a2 47  |dex.035..s.:...G|
00000010  a8 78 a4 f0 bb e1 64 3f  e5 b9 cb a0 bd 1b e2 71  |.x....d?.......q|
00000020
```

[Versions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187829/adb-commands-to-get-the-adb-version-of-mobile-phone)

- adb version               // to check adb client version in your desktop
- adb shell adbd --version  // to check adbd's version in your Android. Please note that some users reported error with this if executed without root access.

```
D:\ProgramFiles\Android>adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.6-6198805
Installed as D:\ProgramFiles\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

D:\ProgramFiles\Android>adb shell adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

Even if restarting adbd as root, it was still the shell user after .

```
D:\ProgramFiles\Android> adb root
restarting adbd as root

D:\ProgramFiles\Android> adb shell id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

So I first viewed its file permision,

```
D:\ProgramFiles\Android> adb shell ls -l /data/local/tmp
-rwsr-sr-x shell    shell      589588 2017-09-14 15:08 android_server
-rwsr-sr-x shell    shell     1243456 2017-09-14 15:08 android_server64
-rw-rw-rw- shell    shell        1536 2020-03-28 17:15 com.packagename.tar.gz
-rw-r----- root     root        57344 2020-03-28 17:45 com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex
drwxrwxr-x shell    shell             2018-08-12 09:48 device-explorer
-rwsrwsr-x shell    shell       13592 2019-02-04 17:44 drizzleDumper
-rwxrwxrwx shell    shell     5512504 2018-05-06 01:27 lldb-server
-rwxr-xr-x shell    shell       12808 2020-03-26 22:16 mprop
```

then, changed its permision,

```
D:\ProgramFiles\Android> adb shell su -c chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/com.packagename_dumped_*

D:\ProgramFiles\Android> adb shell ls -l /data/local/tmp
-rwxrwxrwx root     root        57344 2020-03-28 17:45 com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex
```

As a result, I made it.

```
D:\ProgramFiles\Android> adb pull /data/local/tmp/com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex D:\ProgramFiles\Android\com.packagename_dumped_1766.dex
/data/local/tmp/com.packagename_dumped_1766.de... 1 file pulled, 0 skipped. 3.6 MB/s (57344 bytes in 0.015s)
```

Now, `jadx-gui-dev.exe` or `sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f ~/path/to/apk_to_decompile.apk` could properly enjoy them.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb.exe -d shell "run-as com.shop.tcd cp /data/data/com.shop.tcd/databases/tcd_database.db /sdcard/Download"

adb.exe pull /sdcard/Download/tcd_database.db
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it this way:

```
adb shell
su root
cat /data/user/0/application/databases/ > /storage/self/primary/Download/db_data.db
exit
exit
adb pull /storage/self/primary/Download/db_data.db ~/Desktop/.
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -6):

The `pull` command is:

```
adb pull source dest
```

When you write:

```
adb pull /data/data/path.to.package/databases/data /sdcard/test
```

It means that you'll pull from `/data/data/path.to.package/databases/data` and you'll copy it to `/sdcard/test`, but the destination MUST be a local directory. You may write `C:\Users\YourName\temp` instead.

For example:

```
adb pull /data/data/path.to.package/databases/data c:\Users\YourName\temp
```

Comment: This didn't work either: I still get 'permission denied' error

Comment: mmm... try to get more permissions of the dir you pull from: "adb shell chmod 755 /path/to/dir"

Comment: I get: 'Operation not permitted' error when trying to set permission. Any other ideas?

Comment: don't listen the answer below, you've rooted well, but `adb root` doesn't work in stock ROM, you must write `adb shell` then enter, `su` again enter, and now try change permission again with `chmod 755 /path/to/dir/` I hope this work

Comment: Thanks! I did that and now get the error: 'device not found'. I tried to do it on the file and the directory... but neither worked

Comment: device not found? :/ Can u see device id via `adb devices ` command? however I think you could copy the desidered file in a "more used" directory, like /sdcard/, and pull it from there. Or maybe you could try to browse your phone with qtADB for windows, or an app called Airdroid (gratis on the playstore), that let you browse directories remotely via your PC browser