# Adb pull device not found, yet I'm connected to it

Tags: android

I'm trying to pull a file from my android device using the adb shell. My android is rooted.

If I start adb.exe and execute the command:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db c:\temp
```

I receive the error: "failed to copy, remote permission denied"

So, I then I follow the steps:

```
adb shell -> OK
shell@acer_z200:/ $ su -> OK
root@acer_z200:/ # adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db c:\temp
```

And it gives the error `error: device not found`. So, how in gods heaven I'm able to access the shell and root, and not being connected to the device?

I'm also able to list the files within the folder:

```
root@acer_z200:/ # ls /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/
```

So..the device was not found yet I can list the files?

Comment: Ensure that some instance is running using the command `adb devices -l`

Comment: @MNS yes, it appears my mobile phone. I have already restarted the phone; changed the USB port; restarted the adb using `adb kill-server` but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

After successfully connect to device with `su`, I had to open another shell and execute the `adb pull`.

[copy db file with adb pull results in 'permission denied' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891597/copy-db-file-with-adb-pull-results-in-permission-denied-error)