# Ionic SQLite database - default location on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have a pretty simple problem, I need to find out where the database file created by Ionic Native SQLite plugin exists by default.

I've tried using Windows search, which resulted in rendering the whole file system inaccessible. A desktop search application I use refused to search the storage of my mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to access the database with adb, as explained in this post:

[copy db file with adb pull results in 'permission denied' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891597/copy-db-file-with-adb-pull-results-in-permission-denied-error)

So the command was:

```
adb -d shell "run-as my.package.name cat ./databases/database.db" > database.db
```