# Is it possible to get a GUI for an SQLite database created in flutter for android simulator?

Tags: sqlite, user-interface, flutter, dart

I created a database *main.db* in flutter, located at the *ApplicationDocumentsDirectory.path*. This worked without any problem.

But for easier maintanance and not always having to create an SQL-Statement to see the data or structure I'd like to get a GUI to watch the database. First I wanted to use Browser DB for SQLite but I don't know where the database is saved on my notebook, if so. Also I can't find it with Agent Ransack either.

Is there a way to find the database or maybe an easier way to see the database on a GUI?
I use Visual Studio Code for development if that's any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For Android, the easiest way I have found is to just have Android Studio installed on my machine as well. In Android Studio you can view the database on the device via [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer)

```
View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer.
```

In the new tab make sure your device is selected
e.g

```
MyAndroidDevice > data > data >com.myflutterapp
```

Here you will find your Flutter application files, the main database will be located inside the *'app_flutter folder'*.

Once you've located the database file, right click and save as. You can then open this db file with [BrowserDB](https://www.browserdb.com/) or [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

There might be a similar way to do it with Xcode as well, but I'm not so familiar with that particular IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Just a small addon, if you do not want to install BrowserDB ot sqlitebrowswer, then you can use the following link to view the database online,

https://sqliteonline.com/

Answer (score 3):

*Since this is a top google result for browsing a sqlite db in a simulator for flutter devs, for others who stumble upon this, here's a solution for iOS simulators as well:*

You need to find your db file first, which for iOS sit under `/Users/<youruser>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`. Assuming you know the db name, you could get the full path like this:

```
find /Users/<youruser>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ -name "<name>.db"
```

For example, using `sqflite`'s `getDatabasesPath()` as the location to create the database, I can see the file sits at  `/Users/<youruser>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//<devid>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<appid>/Documents/<name>.db`

And if you were testing on more than one simulator, you can look up the device id with:

```
xcrun simctl list # look under "== Devices ==" or grep for "Booted" if it's running
```

Then browse the db using a tool like `DB Browser for SQLite` as suggested earlier if `sqlite3` is cumbersome. If using vscode, you could give [`SQLTools`](https://vscode-sqltools.mteixeira.dev/) with its SQLite driver a try.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was facing problems with Android Studio so created this executable script.

```
adb exec-out run-as your-package-name cat databases/your_db_name.db > your_db_name.db
sqlite3 your_db_name.db "PRAGMA wal_checkpoint"
start "DB Browser For SQLite.exe" your_db_name.db
```

Of course, you could also have another program in place of DB Browser to open the DB file.

To answer your original question of "where the database is saved", it is saved in the "data/data/your_package/databases" but if you're on Android 10+, the package folder might not be visible to file manager apps without a "special root mode" ( [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/j3zgmm/managing_files_in_the_androiddata_folder_on/) ) because of Scoped Storage.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to F-1 answer if you need a more sophisticated tool for manage your database there is the SQLite Studio. You could do the follow steps to achieve this:

1. To get database (with adb):

   adb -s emulator-5554 pull
   /data/data/com.your.package.yourappname/databases/you_database_name.db .
2. If you need change it and update (It will override android db)

   adb -s emulator-5554 push ~/Desktop/you_database_name.db /data/data/com.your.package.yourappname/databases/
3. Here is the link to SQLite Studio (works in macOS, linux and windows)
   https://sqlitestudio.pl/

Comment: If you run into Permission denied error, checkout this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841916/11689951)

Answer (score 0):

If you got here looking for a macOS solution, VS Code has an **SQLite Extension** and if you saved your db file under the `getDatabasesPath()` directory, you can find it here:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Containers/com.example.flutterApp/Data/Documents
```

Comment: link of the extension?

Comment: This is the one I was using at the time: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Mine is here:

```
C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\device-explorer\Pixel_2_API_31 [emulator-5554]\data\data\br.com.example.myapp\files\db.sqlite
```