# View sqflite table contents for debugging

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am integrating a Database into my flutter app with sqflite. Since I am a visual understander in terms of problems, I would like to be able to see table contents for debugging.

Is there a possibility to view/read the table contents on the phone via some kind of UI or via debug? I am using visual studio code.

Comment: Previously asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159001/is-it-possible-to-get-a-gui-for-an-sqlite-database-created-in-flutter-for-androi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database?utm_source=android-studio) , Use Database Inspector as Code Poet Said
2. IntelliJ IDEA / DataGrip. you can choose Android SQLITE db, and it detect your connected devices.
   [IntelliJ Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWaF8.png)

*dont have enough reputation to post img

Answer (score 3):

You can use Database Inspector at bottom bar of Android Studio to view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open project in Android studio, click on App Inspection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find Database Inspector to see visual of database in android studio and for that you need to open App Inspection
Tools->App Inspection->Database Inspector

Answer (score -1):

If you were willing to move to Android studio, from version 4.1 which is available in the Canary and Dev channels, there is a [Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#database-inspector).

Alternatively, I see that there is a [VS code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools) that might correspond to what you are looking for.

Finally, you could simply use [DB Browser for Sqlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Good luck!

Comment: The sql file should stay in the mobile device. How these tools can connect to those files?