# How to actually view a database in Flutter Floor?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, floor

I am using the Flutter package [floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor) as an SQLite abstraction for my flutter application.

Everything works great so far, but I find it necessary to be able to actively view the database to see how stuff is stored, which data gets removed and so on.

More precisely, I would like to be able to view the database with a DB browser such as the [SQLite browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) for example. How can I access the database visibly, are there possible ways?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this using Android Studio.

For those who are also looking to achieve this, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161560).