# Convertion of .jak files to .java using batch files

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file which will identify the names of all .jak files in a directory (location specified) and convert them to .java files using AHEAD composer.
The batch file code:

```
@echo off

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\AHEAD\ahead-v2013.03.20\build\bin;
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\AHEAD\ahead-v2013.03.20\miscellaneous\javacc\bin;
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Cygwin\bin;

dir C:\AHEAD\JAK\*.jak /b >> list.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (list.txt) do call :Foo %%a
goto End

:Foo
set z=%1
echo %z%
jak2java %z%
goto :eof

:End

PAUSE;

cmd
```

With this i am getting the error `System cannot find batch label specified -Foo`
But the same program works well for `javac` command and `.java` files

Answer (score 0):

Not possible; I tried a simplified version of your code (as below) and it worked fine.

Most probably it's a file format issue. Make sure that the file is in DOS format. Best is; copy the above posted code to a new editor (say, notepad) and save it with `*.bat` extension and then try running it.

Check out this threads as well

[Why "The system cannot find the batch label specified" is thrown even if label exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232651/why-the-system-cannot-find-the-batch-label-specified-is-thrown-even-if-label-e)

http://help.wugnet.com/windows/system-find-batch-label-ftopict615555.html

```
@echo off

dir D:\Songs-mp3\English\*.mp3 /b >> list.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (list.txt) do call :Foo %%a
goto End

:Foo
set z=%1
echo %z%
goto :eof

:End

PAUSE;

cmd
```

Comment: It works for printing the file contents, it even works for "javac" command but when I run the .bat file executing jak2java command it throws the mentioned error.

Comment: @user3594994, that's strange. In that case problem is with `jak2java` and not specific to `batch`. what if you run this command `jak2java X.jak` directly in command prompt. Does it run successfully?

Comment: Yes, if I run jak2java x.jak in command prompt it works successfully. Also it works well even in .bat file when I explicitly mention the file name "x.jak". But I need to get the file names dynamically from a folder.