# Running Babun, Getting error "The system cannot find the batch label specified - CHECKTARGET"

Tags: windows, batch-file, terminal-emulator

I am trying to set up Babun, a terminal emulator (see http://babun.github.io/). However, I am having difficulty simply installing it, getting the following error message:

```
The system cannot find the batch label specified - CHECKTARGET
```

I am following the install instructions from the github page, which are:

"Just download the dist file, unzip it and run the `install.bat` script. After a few minutes babun starts automatically. The application will be installed to the `%USER_HOME%\.babun` directory."

I have run them by going to the directory in the command prompt and then just typing in `install.bat`. I have also tried dragging the `install.bat` file into the terminal.

What do I need to do in order to run install.bat successfully?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you edit `install.bat` ?  Open it in Notepad and search for the label name it says is not there, maybe someone made a typo.

Comment: @foxidrive, I didn't edit the file, but I will give it a go. How would I find out the label name?

Comment: Search for part of the name it displays.  Maybe there is a space in the wrong place which breaks the label.

Comment: Does the `install.bat` file happen to have *nix line-endings? Check out this question: [Windows batch file - The system cannot find the batch label specified](http://stackoverflow.com/q/232651/1380680)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably downloaded the source instead of the install dist.  Try downloading from here: http://babun.github.io/ and run the install.bat provided in that download.

Comment: I ran into this problem and spent about 20 minutes trying to figure out where the directories were that the install.bat pointed to.  Then I realized I downloaded the source instead of the install.